# Visual Basic If..Then..Else String statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My friend and I are working on a simple program for class that allows you to determine the payroll depending on if the string is set to `Processing` or `Sales`. We want it to determine that when you place `Sales` in a text box, it will calculate that with the hours you input. Sales is multiplied by 20.

This is what we have at the moment.

```
Private Sub calcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click

        'declare

        Dim total As Double

        Dim weekly As Double
        Dim weekly1 As Double
        Dim weekly2 As Double
        Dim weekly3 As Double
        Dim weekly4 As Double


        Dim hours1 As Double
        Dim hours2 As Double
        Dim hours3 As Double
        Dim hours4 As Double

        Dim dep1 As Integer
        Dim dep2 As Integer
        Dim dep3 As Integer
        Dim dep4 As Integer

        Double.TryParse(hoursWorked1TB.Text, hours1)
        Double.TryParse(hoursworked2TB.Text, hours2)
        Double.TryParse(hoursWorked3TB.Text, hours3)
        Double.TryParse(hoursWorked4TB.Text, hours4)


        'as decimal


        weeklyPay1.Text = weekly.ToString("C1")
        weeklyPay2.Text = weekly.ToString("C1")
        weeklyPay3.Text = weekly.ToString("C1")
        weeklyPay4.Text = weekly.ToString("C1")


        'sales and processing

        If dep1TB.Text = "Sales" Then
            dep1 = 20
        ElseIf dep1TB.Text = "Processing" Then
            dep2 = 15
        Else : dep1 = 0
        End If

        If dep2TB.Text = "Sales" Then
            dep2 = 20
        ElseIf dep2TB.Text = "Processing" Then
            dep2 = 15
        Else : dep2 = 0
        End If

        If dep3TB.Text = "Sales" Then
            dep3 = 20
        ElseIf dep3TB.Text = "Processing" Then
            dep3 = 15
        Else : dep3 = 0
        End If

        If dep4TB.Text = "Sales" Then
            dep4 = 20
        ElseIf dep4TB.Text = "Processing" Then
            dep2 = 15
        Else : dep4 = 0
        End If

        'calculations

        weekly1 = hours1 * dep1
        weekly2 = hours2 * dep2
        weekly3 = hours3 * dep3
        weekly4 = hours4 * dep4

        total = weekly1 + weekly2 + weekly3 + weekly4

    End Sub
```

Later I determined that we need an As String variable, but everything still returns as 0.

Comment: You need to set the textboxes' text *after* you have done the calculations.

Comment: Seems like you have Option Strict On, I have to congratulate you on that initiative.

Comment: I saw the edit from Tripp and realized it after weeklyPay needed the corrsponding numbers in order to print in the proper text boxes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code that the following commented lines are typos:

```
    If dep1TB.Text = "Sales" Then
        dep1 = 20
    ElseIf dep1TB.Text = "Processing" Then
        dep2 = 15 ' should `dep1` instead?
    Else : dep1 = 0
    End If
```

And here:

```
    If dep4TB.Text = "Sales" Then
        dep4 = 20
    ElseIf dep4TB.Text = "Processing" Then
        dep2 = 15 ' should `dep4` instead?
    Else : dep4 = 0
    End If
```

If so, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
Private Sub calcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim total As Double

    Dim hoursWorkedTBs() As TextBox = { hoursWorked1TB, hoursWorked2TB, hoursWorked3TB, hoursWorked4TB }
    Dim weeklyPayTBs() As TextBox = { weeklyPay1, weeklyPay2, weeklyPay3, weeklyPay4 }
    Dim depTBs() As TextBox = { dep1TB, dep2TB, dep3TB, dep4TB }
    Dim weekly(4) As Double
    Dim hours(4) As Double
    Dim dep(4) As Integer

    For i = 0 to 3
        hours(i) = double.Parse(hoursWorkedTBs(i).Text)
        If depTBs(i).Text = "Sales" Then
            dep(i) = 20
        ElseIf depTBs(i).Text = "Processing" Then
            dep(i) = 15
        Else
            dep(i) = 0
        End If
        weekly(i) = hours(i) * dep(i)
        weeklyPayTBs(i).Text = weekly(i).ToString("C1")
    Next

    total = weekly.Sum()

End Sub
```

Notice that the weekly pay text boxes are updated **after** the calculations are performed. In the most part, that's where your code went wrong.